# How to share methods/classes across websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a class `Arcade.Game` which is available on our `.com` website.  On the same server I have a `.net` website serving static content.  For several design reasons I need to run an `aspx` page on the `.net` site that has access to the `Arcade.Game` class on the `.com` site along with some methods.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: It's easy to create a 3rd project with common classes and reference this project in both sites, no?

Answer (score 0):

Compile `Arcade.Game` and it's dependencies to separate assembly (Class Library project) and reference it from both websites. Be sure to remove it from original website's `App_Code` afterwards.

**Edit:** if you need to access exact same instance of `Arcade.Game` from another website on same server you have other options:

- Run both sites in same AppPool and use reflection to access instance from other application
- Expose methods via WebService if this class is stateless.
- Use .NET Remoting with IPC or TCP channel

Comment: It would make *far* more sense to share a common project between both sites.  Not just drop dlls into the bin directory.

Comment: You are right. Putting DLL in `bin` should be *effect*, not the actual action. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using MVC, look into [Portable Areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/)